# Cokernel of $\mathcal{O}_m\to\mathcal{O}_n$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, projective-varieties

Consider the Serre twisted sheaf $\mathcal{O}_m$ and $\mathcal{O}_n$  with $m<n$ on $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ where $k$ is a field, as $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_m, \mathcal{O}_n)=\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{n-m})$, there exist non-trivial maps $\mathcal{O}_m\to\mathcal{O}_n$.

I'd like to know how to consider the cokernel of some non-trivial map $\mathcal{O}_m\to\mathcal{O}_n$, is it a sheaf with finite support?

Thanks.

Comment: Is $\cal F$ locally free?

Comment: @peterag Sorry, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's consider the special case $n=0$ and $m = -d<0$.
In this case a non-trivial morphism $\mathcal{O}(-d) \to \mathcal{O}$ is given by a degree d homogeneous polynomial $f(x, y) \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P^1}, \mathcal{O}(d)) = k[x, y]_{(d)}$.
Let us denote the closed subscheme $\{f = 0\} \subset \mathbb{P^1}$ by $Z$.
There is a natural exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}(-d) \xrightarrow{f \cdot -} \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}_Z \to 0$$
and therefore the cokernel is the structure sheaf of $Z$.

For general $n$ and $m$, the exact sequence above looks like
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}(n-m) \xrightarrow{f \cdot -} \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}_Z \to 0.$$
By tensoring $\mathcal{O}(m)$ there is another exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}(n) \xrightarrow{f \cdot -} \mathcal{O}(m) \to \mathcal{O}_Z \to 0$$
which illustrates that the cokernel is given by $\mathcal{O}_Z$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to ask that why all non-trivial morphisms is given by a degree $d$ homogeneous polynomial. Also, your last sequence, it shouldn't be $0\to\mathcal{O}(n)\to\mathcal{O}(m)\to\mathcal{O}_Z(m)\to0$?

Comment: We have an isomorphim $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathcal{O}(-d), \mathcal{O}) \cong \Gamma(\mathbb{P^1}, \mathcal{O}(d))$ as you mentioned in the post, and this isomorphism sends $f \in  \Gamma(\mathbb{P^1}, \mathcal{O}(d))$ to the multiplication $f\cdot - \colon \mathcal{O}(-d) \to \mathcal{O}$ by the polynomial $f$. In addition there is an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}(m)_Z \cong \mathcal{O}_Z$ because the line bundle $\mathcal{O}(m)$ is trivial on a neighborhood of $Z$ (which is supported on finite points).